# Vlookup Function in vba having repeated task

Tags: excel, vba

I found this lookup vba from google and I did some modification.
However, I have hard time to figure out the way to resolve the issue of duplicating the coding for same task (explain below)
My objective is to look up one value and return multiples value at one time.
Below are some of my steps:

1. The raw data table (Data Analysis) are from C8 to O399
2. The lookup value are from A5 to A172  and the return result is placed at T5 to T172 (at Sheet name "Graph")
3. Then I repeat again for next look up by duplicating the test code at step 1 and 2 with slight different column
4. I definite again The raw data table (Data Analysis) from C8 to I399 - *Different column than 1st step
5. The lookup value are from A5 to A172 and then return result is placed at V5 to V172 ( at the sheet name "Graph")
6. I repeat again 1 and 2 until I finish lookup up all the multiple return (approximately around 15 values)

So I am having hard time to put this into loop as the value of column and table is changing for every lookup.

Two columns of lookup table for raw data are only allow for every lookup up task (This is different from vkloop which I need to specific the column to look for)
Another point I would like to add is the raw data could go up to a few thousand line and I am seeing this code is using the "Collection" for storeage. I am not sure what this for.

Below are the coding

```
Sub VLookupValues(lookupCategory As Range, lookupValues As Range, vlookupCol As Object)
    Dim i As Long, resArr() As Variant
    ReDim resArr(lookupCategory.Rows.Count, 1)
    For i = 1 To lookupCategory.Rows.Count
        resArr(i - 1, 0) = vlookupCol.Item(CStr(lookupCategory(i)))
    Next i
    lookupValues = resArr
End Sub
```

Any helps is greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

```
Sub TestVBA()
OptimizeVBA True
Dim startTime As Single, endTime As Single
startTime = Timer

Dim testnames As Range, testvalues As Range
Dim lookupTestNames As Range, lookupTestValues As Range
Dim vlookupCol As Object



Set testnames = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("C8:C399")
Set testvalues = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("O8:O399")
   Set lookupTestNames = Worksheets("Graph").Range("A5:A172")
Set lookupTestValues = Worksheets("Graph").Range("T5:T172")

'Set testvalues = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("I8:I" & 399)
'Set lookupTestNames = Worksheets("Graph").Range("A5:A172")
'Set lookupTestValues = Worksheets("Graph").Range("U5:U172")

'Build Collection
Set vlookupCol = BuildLookupCollection(testnames, testvalues)

'Lookup the values
'VLookupValues lookupTestNames, lookupTestValues, vlookupCol
VLookupValues lookupTestNames, lookupTestValues, vlookupCol
endTime = Timer
Debug.Print (endTime - startTime) & " seconds have passed [VBA]"
OptimizeVBA False
Set vlookupCol = Nothing

'For Lower Test Spec****************************************************************
Set testnames = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("C8:C" & 399)
Set testvalues = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("I8:I" & 399)
Set lookupTestNames = Worksheets("Graph").Range("A5:A172")
Set lookupTestValues = Worksheets("Graph").Range("U5:U172")

'Build Collection
Set vlookupCol = BuildLookupCollection(testnames, testvalues)

'Lookup the values
VLookupValues lookupTestNames, lookupTestValues, vlookupCol
endTime = Timer
Debug.Print (endTime - startTime) & " seconds have passed [VBA]"
OptimizeVBA False
Set vlookupCol = Nothing

'For Upper Test Spec****************************************************************

Set testnames = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("C8:C" & 399)
Set testvalues = Worksheets("Data Analysis").Range("J8:J" & 399)
Set lookupTestNames = Worksheets("Graph").Range("A5:A172")
Set lookupTestValues = Worksheets("Graph").Range("V5:V172")

'Build Collection
Set vlookupCol = BuildLookupCollection(testnames, testvalues)

'Lookup the values
VLookupValues lookupTestNames, lookupTestValues, vlookupCol
endTime = Timer
Debug.Print (endTime - startTime) & " seconds have passed [VBA]"
OptimizeVBA False
Set vlookupCol = Nothing
```

Comment: What is `BuildLookupCollection` ?

Comment: If there isn't an order for the lookup values and return values, you should try creating arrays for lookup columns and return value columns. So for each loop you can lookup where you want and return any column you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Ali has the right approach.  A lookup array with column pairs will make looping easier.

---

```
Sub TestVBA2()
    OptimizeVBA True
    Dim startTime As Single
    Dim cSet, vlookupCol As Object

    For Each cSet In Array(Array("I", "T"), Array("J", "U"), Array("O", "V"))
        startTime = Timer

        With Worksheets("Data Analysis").Rows("8:399")
            Set vlookupCol = BuildLookupCollection(.Columns("C"), .Columns(cSet(0)))
        End With

        With Worksheets("Graph").Rows("5:172")
            VLookupValues .Columns("A"), .Columns(cSet(1)), vlookupCol
        End With

        Debug.Print Timer - startTime, "Data Analysis Column:"; cSet(0), "Graph Column:"; cSet(1)
    Next

    OptimizeVBA False

End Sub
```